# Dart.exe moved to virus chest due to IDP.GENERIC

Tags: flutter, dart

New to Flutter learning, after unzipping the latest stable Flutter version 2.0.6 from Flutter.io, every time Avast Antivirus blocks Dart.exe due to 'IDP.GENERIC' found in it and moves it to virus chest. I'm unable to run program from Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I just configured flutter as allowed exception in Avast and it worked. Thanks.